# Keyboard don't hide when touch return in uitextview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I  use the resignFirstResponder in `UITextView` when I touch return but it don't work
 my code

**CommentViewController.h**

```
@interface CommentViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UITextView *commentText;
}
```

**CommentViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
commentText.delegate =self;
}
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
if ([text isEqualToString:@"/n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
else
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: what is "/n" ? Does it correspond to newline in your text ? If it is, then it should be like "\n".

Comment: Ah! I forgot it Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you declare support for the UITextViewDelegate protocol.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

return YES;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the newline character. It's not supposed to be `/n` but `\n`. 
If that doesn't work, I suggest setting a breakpoint in the `if` line and see where the code steps into.

Happy coding!
Z.